# Remove "empty space" in splot with log scaled z axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script which generates a surface plot from data. I've scaled the z axis logarithmically, such as in an example on [gnuplot.info](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/surface1.html)<sup>1</sup> - and just as in the example, I get a lot of empty room at the "bottom" of the plot.

In that example, the ticks on the z axis end at 1, but the axis doesn't end there - the origin of the plot is further "down" (in the z direction).

How do I set the origin to be where the data actually starts? A dynamic approach (that's not dependent on me knowing the data set in advance) is greatly preferred, if it's possible.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Follow the link and search the page for "Surfaces with z log scale" to find the relevant example.</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not an obvious one, but (as usual) there is a setting for that.  Try

```
set xyplane 1
```

and

```
help set xyplane
```

for more details.

Comment: I would use `set xyplane 1` for a log plot

Comment: Great! After reading @psibar's comment, I also expected `set xyplane 0` to yield problems, but it worked just fine. `1` gave results very similar to the ones I had before this, but with smaller values (e.g.  `0.1` or even `0.01`) the result was similar to that with `0`. Regardless, `set xyplane <value>` was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: +1.  I particularly like the bit about "but (as usual) there is a setting for that".